# orientation issue in cropping video file

Tags: objective-c, ios7

hi i'm just simple cropping video file and export it in directory by AVAssetExportSession.
but the problem is portrait video change orientation to landscape and appear as rotated 90 degree in directory in which i've saved.I don't understand how it will be fixed. is there any problem in my code.i hope you will be understand.

```
firstAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:firstUrl];

if(firstAsset !=nil)
{

 AVVideoComposition *origionalComposition = [AVVideoComposition videoCompositionWithPropertiesOfAsset:firstAsset];
    AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];

    //VIDEO TRACK

    AVMutableCompositionTrack *firstTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [firstTrack insertTimeRange:timeRange ofTrack:[[firstAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
```

AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction * MainInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
        MainInstruction.timeRange = timeRange;

```
    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *FirstlayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:firstTrack];
    AVAssetTrack *FirstAssetTrack = [[firstAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];


    [FirstlayerInstruction setTransform:FirstAssetTrack.preferredTransform atTime:kCMTimeZero];

    MainInstruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:FirstlayerInstruction,nil];

    AVMutableVideoComposition *MainCompositionInst = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
    MainCompositionInst.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:MainInstruction];
    MainCompositionInst.frameDuration = origionalComposition.frameDuration;
     MainCompositionInst.renderScale = 1.0;
    MainCompositionInst.renderSize = CGSizeMake(FirstAssetTrack.naturalSize.height, FirstAssetTrack.naturalSize.width);

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Crop Videos"];

    NSString *videoName =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Video_%d.mov",videoNumber];
    NSString *myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:videoName];


    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];

    AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];
    exporter.outputURL=url;
    exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
    [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^
     {
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             [self exportDidFinish:exporter];
         });
     }];
}
```

please answer if anybody know that.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**You haven't added AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction, Make sure you change it accordingly**

```
// 1.0 - Create an AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction for the video track and fix the  orientation.

AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *videolayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack];
AVAssetTrack *videoAssetTrack = [[self.videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];

BOOL isVideoAssetPortrait_  = NO;
CGAffineTransform videoTransform = videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform;
if (videoTransform.a == 0 && videoTransform.b == 1.0 && videoTransform.c == -1.0 && videoTransform.d == 0) {
    isVideoAssetPortrait_ = YES;
}
if (videoTransform.a == 0 && videoTransform.b == -1.0 && videoTransform.c == 1.0 && videoTransform.d == 0) {

    isVideoAssetPortrait_ = YES;
}
if (videoTransform.a == 1.0 && videoTransform.b == 0 && videoTransform.c == 0 && videoTransform.d == 1.0) {
    isVideoAssetPortrait_  = NO;
}
if (videoTransform.a == -1.0 && videoTransform.b == 0 && videoTransform.c == 0 && videoTransform.d == -1.0) {
    isVideoAssetPortrait_  = NO;
}
[videolayerInstruction setTransform:videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform atTime:kCMTimeZero];
[videolayerInstruction setOpacity:0.0 atTime:self.videoAsset.duration];

// 1.2 - Add instructions
mainInstruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:videolayerInstruction,nil];

AVMutableVideoComposition *mainCompositionInst = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];

CGSize naturalSize;
if(isVideoAssetPortrait_){
    naturalSize = CGSizeMake(videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.height, videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.width);
} else {
    naturalSize = videoAssetTrack.naturalSize;
}

mainCompositionInst.renderSize = naturalSize;
mainCompositionInst.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:mainInstruction];
mainCompositionInst.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
```

Comment: thank you, but i am sorry it doesn't working and i've tried many times. is there any other way??????

Comment: What you have done, your code did not reflect that you have used that. Update your code, which you have work through.

Answer (score 0):

This is Running code:

```
AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:"PATH OF VIDEO"]; 
//create mutable composition
AVMutableComposition *mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                                               preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

[compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration)
                                                        ofTrack:[[videoAsset  tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0]
                                                         atTime:kCMTimeZero
                                                          error:&videoInsertError];



AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction * MainInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];

MainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration);

//FIXING ORIENTATION//
AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *FirstlayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:compositionVideoTrack];

AVAssetTrack *FirstAssetTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];

UIImageOrientation FirstAssetOrientation_  = UIImageOrientationUp;

BOOL  isFirstAssetPortrait_  = NO;

CGAffineTransform firstTransform = FirstAssetTrack.preferredTransform;

if(firstTransform.a == 0 && firstTransform.b == 1.0 && firstTransform.c == -1.0 && firstTransform.d == 0)
{
    FirstAssetOrientation_= UIImageOrientationRight;
    isFirstAssetPortrait_ = YES;
}
if(firstTransform.a == 0 && firstTransform.b == -1.0 && firstTransform.c == 1.0 && firstTransform.d == 0)
{
    FirstAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationLeft;
    isFirstAssetPortrait_ = YES;
}
if(firstTransform.a == 1.0 && firstTransform.b == 0 && firstTransform.c == 0 && firstTransform.d == 1.0)
{
    FirstAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationUp;
}
if(firstTransform.a == -1.0 && firstTransform.b == 0 && firstTransform.c == 0 && firstTransform.d == -1.0)
{
    FirstAssetOrientation_ = UIImageOrientationDown;
}

CGFloat FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio = 1.0;

if(isFirstAssetPortrait_)
{
    FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio = FirstAssetTrack.naturalSize.width/FirstAssetTrack.naturalSize.height;
    CGAffineTransform FirstAssetScaleFactor = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio,FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio);
    [FirstlayerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(FirstAssetTrack.preferredTransform, FirstAssetScaleFactor) atTime:kCMTimeZero];
}
else
{
    CGAffineTransform FirstAssetScaleFactor = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio,FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio);
    [FirstlayerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformConcat(FirstAssetTrack.preferredTransform, FirstAssetScaleFactor),CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)) atTime:kCMTimeZero];
}
[FirstlayerInstruction setOpacity:0.0 atTime:videoAsset.duration];

MainInstruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:FirstlayerInstruction,nil];

AVMutableVideoComposition *MainCompositionInst = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
MainCompositionInst.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:MainInstruction];
MainCompositionInst.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
//MainCompositionInst.renderSize = CGSizeMake(FirstAssetTrack.naturalSize.width, FirstAssetTrack.naturalSize.height);
MainCompositionInst.renderSize = [[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] naturalSize];
```

And finally `save` Or 'export' with `AVAssetExportSession` class

```
export.outputURL=FinalPath;
```